# Create Linked Server at MS SQL to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I was wondering how to create synonym at MS SQL Server that will link my Oracle database? My tables all are at Oracle database. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a few more links on linked server from SQL Server to Oracle which enables developers on SQL Server to query data in an Oracle database

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/sql-server-and-oracle-making-connection

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/create-oracle-linked-server-query-data-from-oracle-to-sql-server.aspx

Comment: The second link solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for the feature called 'Linked Server'.
If so, start reading here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a linked server then use synonym on top of that if you need the level of abstraction.

http://www.pressthered.com/sql_server_synonyms_and_linked_servers/

Comment: I need to link to Oracle database. Is that possible?